# Difference Between Application Delegates

Tags: objective-c, delegates, uiapplicationdelegate

What is the difference between:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

and

```
UIApplicationDelegate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UIApplicationDelegate` is a protocol definition, which means it's a set of methods an object that conforms to it should implement.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` is the way you have to ask for application delegate of your currently running application. That delegate should conform to `UIApplicationDelegate`.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.

What about the usual MyApplicationNameAppDelegate vs [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]?

Comment: That's just usually a typecast. You would do `MyApplicationNameAppDelegate *d = (MyApplicationNameAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` and get the delegate casted to the class you use to implement it.